# Baldwin MCX-88 Digital Piano key remove/replace

Tags: keyboard

My Baldwin MCX-88 has 3 broken black keys.  I need to know how to remove and replace the keys.  The keyboard is taken off and easy to access.  I would also like to know where I can find replacement keys, rather than swapping out high/low end seldom used keys.
Thank you..
Randy

Comment: Did you end up taking the keys off? I have a few keys that need to be replaced as well, just curious what your experience was

Answer (score 1):

Ebay may be your friend.  Take a look:

[set of keys](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Vintage-BALDWIN-set-of-88-keys-steampunk-arts-and-crafts-upright-console/253305940652?hash=item3afa35eaac:g:Ou4AAOSwh1haJOCJ)
The other good possibility is to ask any Baldwin dealer/repair shopl.